# How to Sanitize JS Input

Tags: javascript, laravel

Hi I have a Java Script Code for handle Modals and some input data. Code is working fine but Now I have run into a problem after code scanning. Scanning tool is giving me the ***Client Potential XSS*** error and asking me to Sanitize my input.

Error Description:

```
Method $ at line 484 of public/js/Activity/dailyActivity.js gets user input for the attr element. This element’s
value then flows through the code without being properly sanitized or validated and is eventually displayed to
the user in method $ at line 484 of public/js/Activity/dailyActivity.js. This may enable a Cross-Site-Scripting
attack.
```

JS Code:

```
var job_id;

    // Delete action
    $(document).on("click", ".deleteButton", function() {
        var jobcycid = $(this).attr("data-jobcycid");
        job_id = $(this).attr("id");
        $("#deleteModal").modal("show");
        $("#jcId").html(jobcycid);
    });
```

I'm not very good at JS and still at the beginner level. Can anyone tell me how to sanitize this input?

Scan report highlights the following lines:

```
....
485. var jobcycid = $(this).attr("data-jobcycid");
....
488. $("#jcId").html(jobcycid);
```

Comment: Will this matter? As long as you only do things on the front end, this can only wreck the crackers own system. It'll become a problem only if you send this data to the back end. Sanitization also has to be redo on the server, for which this link learn you more https://www.cloudways.com/blog/prevent-xss-exploits-using-laravel-validation-and-sanitization/ But I have no idea what the code scanner would expect you to do here. ParseInt() the id so that it's a number?

Comment: Maybe instead of setting the `.html()`, provide some default HTML so you can update the innerText or an atribute instead of the full HTML. Or explicitly cast the value to a raw string, so that setting the `.html()` will not actually execute anything if I would try to inject a script tag? `<pre>` tag? `<code>` tag? Just throwing out ideas.

Comment: Hi @Shilly...Thank you for your help. Following is an example of the variable:

782867 | 003

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to this.

I have created following function to sanitize any variable generated from HTML value:

```
// Sanitize and encode all HTML in a user-submitted string
    var sanitizeHTML = function(str) {
        var temp = document.createElement("div");
        temp.textContent = str;
        return temp.innerHTML;
    };
```

Then you can use that to sanitize the variable:

```
var jobcycid = sanitizeHTML($(this).attr("data-jobcycid"));
```